# C Pointer To Array; To Primitive

Tags: c, pointers, address-operator

I am using Visual Studio 2015 that isn't displaying compiler warnings related to my use of pointers.  If I am referring for a moment to a pointer `char* p` that points to an array `char name[] = "My Name"`, I don't have any guidance that the following are not all equal; i.e. result in a pointer to the first character of an array

```
char* pname = name; // points to first char in array

printf("\n%c\n", *pname);

pname = &name; // points to first char in array

printf("\n%c\n", *pname);

pname = &name[0]; // this explicitly points to the first char in the array

printf("\n%c\n", *pname);
```

The result of each `printf` is the same value and, because I don't see compiler warnings, I need guidance on which is the correct form.

This is the same for pointer to int whereby I do not see compiler warnings so I assume the following are equivalent

```
int age = 45;
int* page = &age; // point to age
page = age // pointer to age
```

Can someone please clarify this or perhaps help me turn on compiler warnings in Visual Studio 2015 without having to switch to TDM GCC + Eclipse Oxygen.

> Point - Be syntactically specific and correct all warnings

Comment: `The following will also work

page = age;` No, it won't

Comment: Please compile your code and look at warnings / error.. You will have your answer

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious. C is a mature language, it expects it's users to behave the same.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is I am using Visual Studio instead of TDM GCC with Eclipse.  How can I enable compiler warnings?  Also, if they are just warnings and not errors, is my goal to ensure all warnings are corrected before executing the program?

Comment: "*ensure all warnings are corrected before executing the program?*" yes, exactly. Hint: Do not blindly "cast" away warnings.

Comment: @alk I appreciate your advice

Comment: What warnings were you expecting? Of course the results of all the printf's are the same - you're doing basically the same thing three times. Why would you expect different results?

Comment: Stack users are indicating to me what I believe are the same isn't although the results are identical.  I enables compiler warnings in Visual Studio and began to see a different picture.  Right now I assume the address operator can be omitted when pointing to a type and that I don't have to specify the address or initial element of an array when pointing to an array because the results are all the same except when warnings are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> char* pname = name; // points to first char in array
> ```

Correct. When you evaluate an array, you get a pointer to its first element.

> ```
> pname = &name; // points to first char in array
> ```

Incorrect. `&name` is a pointer to the whole array, not just its first element. The assignment is a type error: `pname` is a `char *`, but `&pname` is a `char (*)[8]`.

> ```
> pname = &name[0]; // this explicitly points to the first char in the array
> ```

Correct. The reason this works is because `a[b]` is defined as `*(a + b)`. So `&name[0]` really means `&*(name + 0)`. As before, the array evaluates to the address of its first element. Adding `0` doesn't change it. `*` dereferences the pointer, but `&` goes back to the address (they cancel each other out).

> ```
> int age = 45;
> int* page = &age; // point to age
> ```

Correct.

> ```
> page = age; // pointer to age
> ```

Incorrect. This is a type error: `age` is an `int` but `page` is an `int *`.

What source are you learning C from?

Unfortunately I can't tell you how to configure Visual Studio 2015 as I've never used it before. Have you tried reading its manual?

Comment: Hm, this in fact is not an answer, but well ... 1+ anyway. ;-)

Comment: @alk Well, the question cannot be answered as asked because it is based on faulty assumptions (the "shortened versions" are very different code). I tried to answer "what should I do".

Comment: Can you provide a better answer?  As in can you demonstrate how a pointer that points to a type that doesn't use an address operator is the proper way to declare a pointer variable?  I will revise my question.

Comment: @Mushy I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I tend to annotate such kind of "answers" with a prefix like "*[too long for a comment]*".

Comment: @melpomene I reformed my question to address specifics brought up by others through comments and to specify assistance with Visual Studio 2015  compiler warnings

Comment: @melpomene I am learning from The C Programming Language (ANSI C) by Kerighan & Ritchie.  I need clarification on this because the equivalencies I mention, if you run the code above, all produce the same result which makes learning pointers, indirection, and address confusing somewhat